# Discord bot python DM message before kicking

Tags: python, bots, discord

I'm pretty new to discord bots so i wondered if someone here could help me, I wrote a code for kicking and i want to add something that DM's the person before he gets kicked but after the !kick command was given.

```
@bot.command()
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member=None):
    if not member:
        await ctx.send('Please mention a member')
        return
    await member.kick()
    await ctx.send(f'{member.display_name}\'s was kicked from the server')
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a dm channel and send the message.

Try adding the two lines below:

```py
@bot.command()
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member is None:
        await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention} Please mention a member')
        return
    channel = await member.create_dm() # line 1 create channel
    await channel.send('You are getting kicked') # line 2 send the message
    await member.kick()
    await ctx.send(f'{member.display_name}\'s was kicked from the server')
```